# What is the fix for "NMAKE: fatal error u1073"?

Tags: nmake

I am trying to install apr-1.4.5 in Windows. When I try the following,

```
nmake Makefile.win PREFIX="c:\Program Files\apr"
```

I get the following error:

```
NMAKE: fatal error u1073: Dont know how to make 'Makefile.win'
```

Does anyone know the reason for this and how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 2):

To specify the name of the makefile you should use `/f` command line option:

```
nmake /f Makefile.win PREFIX="c:\Program Files\apr"
```

Regular nmake parameters are considered to be build targets - and there is no build target called `Makefile.win` which is what the error message was trying to tell you.